# Forwarding of CiviMail to addresses on same hosting service fails

Tags: civimail

I have email accounts at the hosting service that hosts my CiviMail 4.6.2 in WordPress 4.1.7. The accounts forward mail to other addresses. I.e. CiviCRM is on www.mydomain.com and the addresses are @mydomain.com, but the mail is forwarded elsewhere.

Non-CiviMail email from CiviCRM to these @mydomain.com addresses is received but CiviMail is reported as "success" but is never received, not seen as spam.  CiviMail to other addresses (@elsewhere.com) is received. (In a CiviMail mailing that includes both @mydomain.com and @elsewhere.com the @elsewhere.com posts arrive and @mydomain.com posts don't.)

CiviMail to @mydomain.com used to work, apparently stopped several months ago.

What configuration should I be looking at in order to get this going again?

(Most, but not all, of the @mydomain.com addresses forward to Google Apps mail servers. However the non-receipt affects all @mydomain.com addresses, not just the ones handed on to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM .)

Answer (score 3):

The hosting company mail server was objecting to VERP mailoxes like
`Return-Path: b.544.88425.a5cada51f4f1fa94@mydomain.com`
that are not prefixed with a real mailbox, treating them as unknown addresses and discarding the post. The discarding is noted in the logs, which are not available to me.

There is a setting CiviCRM > Adminster > CiviMail > Mail Accounts
in which "Localpart" of the Bounce record needs to be a host mailbox followed by "+" e.g "reply-mail+".
(There is also a setting "Return-Path" which seems to be ignored, at least if VERP is being used.)
Localpart gets prefixed to the VERP addresses to make, e.g.
`Return-Path: <reply-mail+b.578.89179.a1e28883fd23b0e3@mydomain.com>`
and the addresses are no longer seen as unknown and the posts are sent on their way. Delivery was ultimately successful to Gmail apps mail (where it usually went to the Promotions tab) and to other services.

[This post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2314/how-does-civimail-reply-tracking-and-forwarding-work/2327#2327) is pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have done the obvious thing of making @mydomain.com an allowed sender on all you accounts?

I am only asking because starting a few months ago we have found that CiviMail emails that previously was being delivered successfully to @gmail.com or @hotmail.com accounts started to just 'vanish' (not received and not in spam). Specifically listing @ourdomain.com as acceptable in those accounts stopped the emails from 'vanishing".

I realise you are talking about @mydomain.com email addresses, but the timing and the fact that the emails 'vanish' made me think it was worth mentioning.

Comment: (Sorry about the lack of line breaks in the following.)

The "allowed sender" would be the domain from the `From:` header?  

This is as sent from CiviCRM email contact (not CiviMail), and it arrived  

`From: "Eric Lee" <eric@mydomain.com>`

This is as sent from CiviMail to ericlee@elsewhere.com and arrived (sent to but never arrived at eric@mydomain.com)

`From: "My Company" <Info@MyDomain.Com>`

It's the same domain, except for mixed case, which I assume doesn't matter.

Comment: I added info@mydomain.com as contact in outlook.com and gmail.com and sent the CiviMail again but it only arrived at the @elsewhere.com address.