# How are CiviMail VERP tracking addresses contructed?

Tags: civimail, bounce

The CiviMail reply and bounce tracking VERP addresses seem to include multiple + signs in the address.

Eg. **donotreply+r+21+21+ae1dc2b1ec827788@** , donotreply+ being the localpart

Office 365 now supports plus addressing (https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=59441), which works with a single + character in the address, but addresses with multiple + characters are rejected (unknown address).

Is there a way to change the generated string to not include the extra + signs?

Edit - Had missed a CiviMail setting. VERP separator character can be specified at /civicrm/admin/mail?reset=1

The breakdown of VERP address is detailed in an answer to another question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/2327/2266

Comment: +r+21+21+ 
r seems to indicate 'reply' tracking action, and +21+21 seems to reflect the message id? I thought these elements were supposed to be separated by full stops?

Comment: My mistake - for some reason the VERP separator in CiviMail config (/civicrm/admin/mail?reset=1) was set to +